# why lodash union method not take single element to array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, lodash

I am trying to update an empty array in Postgres DB using lodash `_.union` method. when I update the array with a single element the array remains empty and if I pass the 2 or more elements it works why? and how to insert a single element into an empty array.

how I defined the product model

```
  variation: {
    type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
    defaultValue: [],
    allowNull: true,
  },
```

union method

```
    const id = req.params.id;
    const { variation } = req.body;

    const isVariation = await products.findOne({
      where: { product_id: id },
    });
    

    const variationArray = isVariation.variation;
    let newlist = _.union(variationArray, variation);

    await products.update(
      { variation: newlist},
      { where: { product_id: id } }
    );
```

if I test this code it will work, but the above code not works why?

```
    let arr = [];
    let ok = _.union(arr, ["1"])
    console.log(ok);
```

Comment: Show debugging details. What do you mean by "not works"?

Comment: not working means a single element is not pushing into array

Answer (score 0):

To insert a single element into an empty array, I used a conditional statement to handle the case separately.

```
    const variationArray = isVariation.variation;
    let newlist;
    if (variationArray.length === 0) {
      newlist = [variation];
    } else {
      newlist = _.union(variationArray, variation);
    }
```